# Creating custom types with optional parameters

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a custom type within typescript to help with the validation in the package which I am building. The aim is to guide the user how to actually perform validation by using the type to hint to the user the format. I have this working, however, I've hit a stumbling block when string to make this optional as not all parameters are required.

I am doing the following:

```js
const _string = '';

export type ValidationRules = {
  `between:${typeof _string},${typeof _string}`
}
```

However, there is some additional rules whereby configuration can be passed in using the comma as the delimiter. For example:

`required_if:{name},{value | operator},{value?}`

In the above scenerio, the value on the end of the string is optional but if I do it like previously described.

```js
const _string = '';

export type ValidationRules = {
  `required_if:${typeof _string},${typeof _string},${typeof _string}`
}
```

The hint then becomes `required_if:,,` whereas realistically I want it to be `required_if:,`

I know I can duplicate it as another type like:

`required_if:${typeof _string},${typeof _string}`

But i didn't know if there was an easier way to this by making it optional.

Is there also anything which can be done doc wise in order to hint to the user what they are populating?

UPDATE:

```js
export enum Operator {
    Equals = 'eq',
    GreaterThan = 'gt',
    LessThan = 'lt'
}

export type ValidationRules = 
    `required_if:${string},${string}` |
    `required_if:${Operator}(${string},${string})`

const valid: ValidationRules = 'required_if:name,exampleName'; // Pass
const valid2: ValidationRules = 'required_if:eq(name,exampleName)'; // Pass

const invalid: ValidationRules = 'required_if:name,exampleName,exampleName'; // Fail
const invalid2: ValidationRules = 'required_if:invalid(name,exampleName)'; // Fail
```

[Please find a link to a Typescript playground with some types:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwPJmFAhjaOAbwCg5y4BRAR2VwBsBnOAXjgHJhr2AaMigOJRg+HABUAFrkSsOAcxi9+5ADLBGjSdNnt6ikgF8SJUJFhwYAT2xwAagwCWAE3wOIiAErJ662crgABsK0DsJOAPoOAGYAXAAkRIwwUA6IcgY8CUkpaQYBcAA+-kFcyKHAEdHxRFg4+NAGABRZyanpmYmtuQCUAcYAxu5JcABujk4xduOu7l4+zGzswWVhkbGIuKjAPKCbYD4AcpvA7ADccAD0F3AACrgaJIOIw2P0zgBMk-ZvLjBunt5fItluVKrEuI0NlsdiA9odjt0zpdrncHo8hvBUq9nF9pn9ZoCFhwQasqlDtrtUPtgEdoZTqbSTucrnAAGK4Bz0dHPTGIbFOT5TH4zAHzHQkiprGJY8aQ44wuE0hFIlnszkkIA)

In the link above I've added the types as I have them defined. I believe, that the confusion comes from the string. Technically, the type is a string so it's behaving correctly. However, I don't know if there is a way to avoid this to enforce one of the Operator enum values to be used.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ① Your example code has typos; the `ValidationRules` type is invalid; please [edit] to fix it so it's a [mre] we can all work on. ② I'm confused by a template literal type that hardcodes `typeof _string` when `_string` has a string literal type; you'll just get a string literal type out, at which point you might as well just write that type manually.  Could you demonstrate some use cases in your [mre]? ③ You could maybe do something like [this approach](//tsplay.dev/weL8VW), but I'm not sure it meets your needs because of the prev questions. What am I missing?

Comment: I have added a link to a playground with an example which might be a bit more clear.

Comment: The code should be included as plaintext, not just as a playground link.  Could you edit to include it?

Comment: @jcalz I have added the code into the question, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a top class Typescript type UX (deep object validation + autocompletions + type error explanations) (but it's hard to write), you may use Validated Type pattern:

```
// returns the type itself if it's a proper type, or a error if not
type conforms<T, Valid, Error = Valid> = unknown extends T ? Error : T extends Valid ? Valid : Error;
// returns type itself if it's correct, or autocompletion/inline error if not
type validateValidationRule<T> =
    | T extends `required_if:${infer O extends Operator}(${infer A},${infer B},${string})` ? `required_if:${O}(${A},${B})` // disallow :(,,)
    : T extends `required_if:${Operator}(${string},${string})` ? T // ok
    : T extends `required_if:${Operator}(${string}` ? `required_if:${Operator}(${string},${string})`
    : T extends `required_if:${infer A},${infer B},${string}` ? `required_if:${A},${B}` // disallow :,,
    : T extends `required_if:${infer A},${infer B}` ? T // ok
    : ( // default fallback
        | `required_if:?,?`
        | `required_if:${Operator}(?,?)`
    )

function ensureValidationRule<T>(value: conforms<T, validateValidationRule<T>>) {
    return value as T
}

ensureValidationRule('required_if:gt(?,?)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
type r = `required_if:${typeof _string},${typeof _string}${'' | `,${typeof _string}`}`
```

(it does unwrap to

```
type r = `required_if:${typeof _string},${typeof _string}` | `required_if:${typeof _string},${typeof _string},${typeof _string}`
```

so you may use that ine as well
)

Comment: That's all I can say, your question is hard to understand (and it has invalid TS code)

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to a ts playground which might make it a bit easier to understand what I am trying to achieve. Apologies.